# How to show images from filepath in a shiny report?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe in which I store the URLs of images as well as some other imformation as follows:

```
structure(list(DxRaw = list(NA_character_, "some intersting fdsfsd ", 
    "tralalalala"), 
    url = list(NULL, c("![](S:/Seb/Image.files/img35.jpg)", 
    "![](S:/Seb/Image.files/ img36.jpg)"
    ), NULL)), .Names = c("DxRaw", "url"), row.names = 37:39, class = "data.frame")
```

I had generated the URL column using pander as follows:

```
library(pander)
mergeddf$url<-sapply(mergeddf$url,pandoc.image.return)
```

I would like to show the images (stored on a local Windows filesystem) when the table is rendered using pander in a word document generated using shiny in R as follows:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
pander(Alltbl,justify='left',split.table=Inf,caption="Table 4: ")
```
````

How can I show the images. What do I have to write in the rmd file or do I do this from the R script itself?

Comment: It seems something went wrong with generating the images, as a markdown formatted image reference would look like as `![](S:/Seb/Image.files/img35.jpg)` (in your example it's doubled). With correct markup, images in the table should render fine.

Comment: @daroczig what do you mean it's doubled? There are two different image paths with a list img35 and img 36

Comment: Ah, sorry, that indeed [works](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=------------------------%0A+a+++++++++++b++++++++++%0A---+--------------------%0A+1+++!%5B%5D(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fx.png)+%0A------------------------%0A%0A-------------------------------------------%0A+a+++++++++++++++++++++b+++++++++++++++++++%0A---+---------------------------------------%0A+1+++!%5B%5D(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fx.png)%2C!%5B%5D(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fy.png)+%0A-------------------------------------------%0A&from=markdown&to=html)